Isometric Embeddings
I wanted to ask about isometric embeddings (which i believe to be a map that preserves distance) between normed space.
Specifically I am looking at problems creating isometric embeddings between the spaces $(\text{dom}(A), ||A \cdot||), (\text{dom}(A^{\frac{1}{2}}), ||A^{\frac{1}{2}} \cdot||)$ and $(\text{dom}(A^{-\frac{1}{2}}), ||A^{-\frac{1}{2}} \cdot||)$, where $A$ is a linear operator.
I am wondering two things in this case, as this was a quick introductory course into spectral theory, and the prerequisites were not covered. Firstly I wonder what the norm $||A \cdot||$ means. I understand its the norm of $A$ acting on an element of it domain, but in that case which norm is used, or does it matter in the case of isometric embeddings.
Then I wonder what sort of distance is to be preserved by these isometric embeddings. Is it for example a map $f:D(A) \rightarrow D(A^{\frac{1}{2}}) \text{ s.t. } ||A(\phi_1 - \phi_2)|| = ||A^{\frac{1}{2}}(f(\phi_1) - f(\phi_2))||$ or something else entirely.
I apologise if this question is very basic, or seems obvious or silly, but like I said, I only took a very short introductory course into spectral theory, from which these problems are from. Thank you.

There is an original norm $|\cdot|$ on the normed space you are considering. The norm $|A\cdot|$ simply means the norm $x \mapsto |Ax|$. For the “what sort of distance is to be preserved” question, your understanding is correct - though since we’re working with norms, preserving distances and preserving norms are the same, so you only need a linear map $f: D(A) \to D(A^{1/2})$ s.t. $|Ax| = |A^{1/2}f(x)|$. Such an $f$ automatically preserves distances in the sense you wrote down. (Of course, $f$ is really just $A^{1/2}$ restricted to $D(A)$.)
